# A letter from J. P. Serre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory

Which is the letter where J. P. Serre present "Analogues Kählériens de certaines conjectures de Weil" to Weil?

Comment: Dear mateo what type of information are you searching for? An extract of this letter ("du 9 novembre 1959") is published in Annals of maths:
Serre, Jean-Pierre
"Analogues kählériens de certaines conjectures de Weil." 
Ann. of Math. (2) 71 1960 392–394.

Comment: The letter appears (with this title) in Ann. of Math. 71 (1960), 392–394.

Answer (score 5):

In order to mark this answered, the letter appears in Ann. of Math. 71 (1960), 392–394.